# Formula to change another cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, cell

I'm a novice in excel. I'm using Excel 2010. My spreadsheet looks something like this:

```html
0 A B  C D

1 X 10€  X: (sum of all incomes, made by A)
2 Y 20€  Y: (sum of all incomes, made by B)
3 Z 5€  Z: (sum of all incomes, made by C)
4 X 4€
5 Z 6€
```

I have a list of incomes and outcomes, collected/paid for by 3 different persons. I'd like to format the first column: if the content of the cell is 'X', the income in that row is added to X's sum of all incomes, if it's Y, add to Y's sum, same for Z.

Something like this (for A1):
"if content = X, add B1 to D1; if content = Y, add B1 to D2; if content = Z, add B1 to D3"

How do I write the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `=SUMIF()` formula.

Before you start, remove the colons from C1, C2 and C3.

In D1 write this formula:

`=SUMIF($A$1:$A$5,C1,$B$1:$B$5)`

... and copy or drag the formula down to D2 and D3.

Remember the $-signs in the formula to lock the ranges when copying or dragging.